# Unable to Export (or view) Total If-Idf Results for textmining

Tags: r, rstudio, text-mining, tf-idf

As part of my efforts to textmine research papers I am interested in looking at Tf-Idf values.

So far I have had difficulty using tidytext for tf-idf due to issues with columns/objects not being detected (consistent issue on this site). Therefore I utilised TM weighting and hoped to view all my results by exporting to csv.

The limited results that I have are in the right format (paper; term; tf-idf value). Only a few of the papers though are available. This is despite the fact that the object states that there are 71 documents. (One document is not readable therefore shows up with error that can be ignored.)

Any help is appreciated, cheers

```
setwd('C:\\Users\\[--myname--]\\Desktop\\Text_Mine_TestSet_1')
files <- list.files(pattern = 'pdf$')
summary(files)

corpus_a1 <- Corpus(URISource(files),
                    readerControl = list(reader = readPDF()))

TDM_a1 <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus_a1, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                                       stopwords = TRUE,
                                                       tolower = TRUE,
                                                       stemming =TRUE,
                                                       removenumbers = TRUE))
DTM_a1 <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus_a1, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                                       stopwords = TRUE,
                                                       tolower = TRUE,
                                                       stemming =TRUE,
                                                       removenumbers = TRUE))

# --------------------------

tdm_TfIdf <- weightTfIdf(TDM_a1)
tdm_TfIdf # 71 Documents 32,177 terms (can sparse here)
tdm_TfIdf %>% 
  View() # Odd table
inspect(tdm_TfIdf) # Shows limited output
print(tdm_TfIdf)

library(devtools)

tdm_inspect <- inspect(tdm_TfIdf)
tdm_DF <- as.data.frame(tdm_inspect, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tdm_DF
write.table(tdm_DF)
write.csv(tdm_DF, 'C:\\Users\\Hunter S. Baggen\\Desktop\\tdm_TfIdf.csv',
          row.names = TRUE)

# ---------------------
# SAME ISSUE SIMPLY X and Y AXIS FLIPPED
dtm_TfIdf <- weightTfIdf(DTM_a1)
dtm_TfIdf # 71 Documents 32,177 terms (can sparse here)
dtm_TfIdf %>% 
  View() # Odd table
inspect(dtm_TfIdf) # Shows limited output
print(dtm_TfIdf)

dtm_inspect <- inspect(dtm_TfIdf)
dtm_DF <- as.data.frame(dtm_inspect, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dtm_DF
write.table(dtm_DF)
write.csv(dtm_DF, 'C:\\Users\\Hunter S. Baggen\\Desktop\\dtm_TfIdf.csv',
          row.names = TRUE)
```

As stated above, four papers and ten terms appear in the resulting csv file. I am unsure why the results would be limited in this manner.

Comment: The reason for this is that you use `dtm_inspect <- inspect(dtm_TfIdf)`. `inspect` only shows 10 columns (and 10 rows if available) and should never be used for assigning data to an object. Only use `inspect` to have a quick view of the data. If you want to export the data, use the dtm_TfIdf object.

Comment: `as.matrix(tdm_TfIdf )`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I was able to accomplish this goal (though not another related one I posted about and is related to my work). Most important, I used Cermine (https://github.com/CeON/CERMINE) who I cannot thank enough and will cite in my work. This allowed me to convert my .pdf into .txt while keeping document format.

In regards to exporting TFIDF values to .csv files (in Excel) I also had a great deal of help. This help, however, has no original reference point that I can find; I found it from someone who sourced it from another etc. After making a dataframe (DF <- function(x,y)) export each as a sheet within Excel (.csv file) with this code:
*NB please take credit if you wrote this script it has been immensely useful

```
xlsx.writeMultipleData <- function (file, ...)
{
  require(xlsx, quietly = TRUE)
  objects <- list(...)
  fargs <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
  objnames <- as.character(fargs)[-c(1, 2)]
  nobjects <- length(objects)
  for (i in 1:nobjects) {
    if (i == 1)
      write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i])
    else write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i],
                    append = TRUE)
  }
}

xlsx.writeMultipleData('filename.xlsx',
                       Dataframe_A, Dataframe_B, etc)
```